# SKaction blocked touchesBegan event

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, skaction

I have a grid with different square. When user click in the square this square do a flip. But during the time of this flip the event of `touchesBegan` didn't work.

This code is execute after click in square :

```
 func flipTile(node : RectSprite){
    let flip = SKAction.scaleXTo(-1, duration: 0.5)
    let flip2 = SKAction.scaleXTo(-1, duration: 0.2)

    node.setScale(1.0)
    var key : String = Array(CircleColor.colors.keys.array)[10]
    var changeColor = SKAction.runBlock( { node.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"white")})
    var removeCombinaison = SKAction.runBlock( {
        self.combination.last?.removeFromParent()
        self.combination.removeLast()
        self.updateGrid()

    })

    var action = SKAction.sequence([flip, changeColor])
    var action2 = SKAction.sequence([flip2, removeCombinaison] )

    node.imageName = "white"
    node.name = "square"
    node.runAction(action)
    self.combination.last?.runAction(action2)
}
```

But if i click fast in the next square the event touch didn't work. Maybe i need to execute this code in the new thread.

Comment: What did you use in touchesBegan to check

Comment: i use nodeAtPoint and isEqualToNode. I don't check if I passing in touchesBegan or if  my condition didn't work. I check this evening. Thank you.

Comment: Thank but it's the stucture of my code was not good. Because i delete SKSpriteNode of my array after flip animate. So i compare my square touched with combination at n index but i need to compare with the n - 1 index if my SKAction is not finish. thank you for your help I could understand my mistake.

Comment: yeah, good for you. Good luck building your app!!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to check the touch position using (I think this even works during the flip animation):

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if yourNode.containsPoint(location) {
        /* called whenever the square is touched */
        } else {
        /* called when some other location on the screen is touched */
        }
    }
}
```